Align content bellow bar buttons in navigation bar in SwiftUI
I'm trying to align vertical content bellow the navigation bar with the left and right bar buttons of the navigation bar. (see screenshot)

Actually the second row (searchBar) and third row (custom segmented control) have a hard coded leading padding of 16px.
It is perfectly aligned in my iPhone 15 simulator... but not in my iPhone 11 (screenshot). So I thing the padding at the left of the navigation bar button is different depending the devices used.
How to know how much pixels/points are at the left of this navigation bar button depending the device ?
I think Safe area can't help in my case.
Thanks
